# Why does COUNT return NULL instead of `0` in this query?

Tags: sqlite, count, aggregate-functions

I have the query

```
select d.did, count ( h.did ), unique_interested
from dealer as d
  left outer join house as h
    on h.did = d.did
  left outer join (
    -- cid = customer id
    select hid, count (cid) as unique_interested
    from is_interested
    group by hid
  ) as ok
    on h.hid = ok.hid
group by d.did
order by d.did asc
;
```

which is supposed to select the number of houses that each dealer is dealing, and the number of unique customers interested in said houses (as in the number of customers per dealer). This should happen even if the dealers have no houses to deal at the moment, which is why I'm using `left outer join`s when constructing the table the columns will be picked from.

Now, running this query against my database produces the following output:

```
d.did  count ( h.did)  unique_interested
-----  --------------  ----------------
1           3                                
2           3              1                 
3           0
```

As you can see, instead of printing `0` in the last column, `count` returns null, when there is a `null` in one of the aparments produced by the last part of the join (as in `cid is null`):

```
select hid, count ( cid ) as unique_interested
from is_interested
group by hid
```

I know this is because there are apartments in the table produced by `from`, that no-one is interested in. But shouldn't count produce `0` instead of the actual column value `null` in every case?

Any explanation as to why this is happening would be appreciated, as it would lead me towards an answer to another question, which is "Why am I not getting the right number of unique interested customers per dealer from the table is_interested?", as with the current state of my database, the output should look more like:

```
d.did  count ( h.did)  unique_interested
-----  --------------  ----------------
1           3              2                 
2           3              2                 
3           0              0
```

Comment: *But shouldn't count produce 0 instead of the actual column value null in every case?* No because `count (cid) as unique_interested` is counting from the table `is_interested`. If a house is not in that table is not counted and the join will result to null.

Comment: If you want to see 0 instead of null use coalesce(): `select d.did, count ( h.did ), coalesce(unique_interested, 0)...`